# Own Authorization attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In the existing system, we need to rebuild the user's authorization.

The database includes Roles and Rights

Roles were previously used but will be skipped in the new version

All authorization will be based on Rights control

I have prepared an attribute that performs such a task

Controller:

```
[HasRights(Rights.AddPayer, Rights.DeletePayer)]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPayer([FromBody]PayerModel model)
{
}
```

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class HasRightsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    HashSet<Rights> userRights;

    public HasRightsAttribute(params Rights[] rights)
    {
        userRights = rights.ToHashSet();
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        Claim claim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault();
        int userId = int.Parse(claim.Value);

        List<int> rights;

        using (var myContext = new myDB())
        {
            rights = (from UR in myContext.TblUserRole
                      join RR in myContext.TblRoleRight on UR.RoleID equals RR.RoleID
                      where UR.UserID == userId
                      select RR.RightID)
                      .ToList();
        }

        var permission = rights.Any(x => userRights.Contains((Rights)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Rights), x)));

        if (!permission)
        {
            //context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            Debug.WriteLine("NO ACCESS");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("YOU HAVE ACCESS");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good direction?

What can be corrected / changed?

Comment: I would implement this attribute as a factory, see _Custom Filter Factories_ on [Dependency Injection in action filters in ASP.NET Core](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core) so that you can also inject your repository.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks like it's going to query the database to check for their permissions on every single request. It might be a better idea to store their rights in their session or signed token instead.